# Why do system calls need to be restarted after they receive a signal?

Tags: linux, signals

When a process receives a signal and the signal is handled the process doesn’t restart, from my understanding the only that need to be restablished is the signal handler.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question correctly. The way I understand it, this would be a duplicate of: [`EINTR`: is there a rationale behind it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253349/eintr-is-there-a-rationale-behind-it)